# I want to create a running subtotal for costs in PHP with data from SQL

Tags: php, sql, multiple-columns

I am unable to locate the answer on here. Hopefully someone can help.

I want the table to display a running total of Xproducts to Xcost.
I get the data from an SQL database and have been stuck on this for months.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false 
language: lang-css -->

<?php
//Create a table to fill in
echo("<table border=1>");
echo("<tr><th>Image</th><th>Name</th><th>Product Description</th><th>Inventory</th><th>Cost</th><th>Order</th><th>Total</th></tr>");
require_once("serverCode/connect.php");
$sql = "Select * FROM products;";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Jquery associate number with the textbox for each product
    // dynamic on the fly (after is simpler )
    $id = $row['productsID'];
    /*Start columns*/    echo("<tr>");
    /*Image column*/     echo("<td><img src='images/" . $id . ".jpg'"    . "</td>");
    /*Name column*/      echo("<td>" . $row['productsName'] . "</td>");
    /*Image column*/     echo("<td>" . $row['productsDesc'] . "</td>");
    /*Inv column*/       echo("<td>" . $row['productsInv'] . "</td>");
    /*Cost column*/      echo("<td>" . $row['productsCost'] . "</td>");
    /*orderAmt column*/  echo("<td><input type=text name = 'product_$id'></td>");
    /*Subtotals column*/ echo("<td>"  "</td>");
    /*end columns*/      echo("</tr>");
}
echo("<tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>FINALTotal</th></tr>");
    /*end table*/        echo("</table>")   
?>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

I don't  think I posted the data right, but hopefully, this helps

Below is a picture of what it looks like
I have highlighted where subtotals should go and final total as well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Zhd.png)

Comment: Add a variable outside your while, to hold the total. Inside the loop add the current item price to the variable. Output the variable to the page

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. I am very slow with this stuff. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Lily and welcome to stackoverflow.

Your code is a mess, I tried to fix it somewhat, but I didn't check everything. Please try this one:

```
<?php
require_once("serverCode/connect.php");

//Create a table to fill in
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr><th>Image</th><th>Name</th><th>Product Description</th><th>Inventory</th><th>Cost</th><th>Order</th><th>Total</th></tr>";

$sql = "Select * FROM products;";    
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

// add a variable to store the running subtotal in:
$subtotal = 0;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    // add the cost of the current product to $subtotal
    // and make sure it is a float value:
    $subtotal += floatval($row['productsCost']);

    $id = $row['productsID'];
    echo "<tr>";    // Start columns*/    
    echo "<td><img src=\"images/$id.jpg\"/></td>";  // Image column     
    echo "<td>" . $row['productsName'] . "</td>";   // Name column
    echo "<td>" . $row['productsDesc'] . "</td>";   // Image column     
    echo "<td>" . $row['productsInv'] . "</td>";    // Inv column
    echo "<td>" . $row['productsCost'] . "</td>";   // Cost     
    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"$id\"></td>"; // orderAmt column
    // output the subtotal:
    echo "<td>$subtotal</td>";  // Subtotals column
    echo "</tr>";       // end columns
}
echo "<tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>FINALTotal</th></tr>";
echo "</table>";        // end table
?>
```

Outside the while-loop you declare a variable $subtotal. Within the loop you add the currect product cost to it (+= operator) and print it to the table. I have added comments where this happens.

Furthermore I would recommend you to [find a php tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/) and learn the language before you start bigger projects. Have fun!

Comment: This helped a huge amount!